# call a powerpoint macro with arguments from batch

Tags: vba, batch-file, powerpoint

I want to call a powerpoint macro from my batch file like this

`"c:\program files\microsoft office\office14\POWERPNT.exe" /M x5_template.pptm macro_name(argument)`

Problem is that it's working fine without argument but my requirement is to pass the argument. Any words on it how to pass the argument?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:  Write an EXE that accepts your parameters on the command line.
The EXE then invokes PowerPoint and calls the macro and passes any necessary parms.
Here's a VB snippet that might help:

```
Dim oPPTapp As Object
Set oPPTapp = New PowerPoint.Application

' make it visible if need be
oPPTapp.Visible = True  

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    oPPTapp.Quit
    Set oPPTapp = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

' Call PPT VBA subroutine using Parameter, which you've
' parsed from the command line
oPPTapp.Run "NameOfSubRoutine", Parameter
```

You could make it even more generic if you use the first command line parm as the name of the macro to run and then pass any further parm(s) as parameter(s)

Comment: I have originally thought of the same but I dont want to write any wrapper, that was the concern. Anyways, created the wrapper but getting error as **application.run invalid request sub or function not defined 80048240 ** on running the vbs.

Comment: You might want to post the exact code you're using.  The snippet I posted above was VB5/6 code, not VBS, btw.  Also, the sub in PPT you're trying to run would need to be declared Public and would need to be part of a loaded add-in or would need to be hosted in an open PPT file (ie the one you're loading at startup).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't.

But, I use the following strategy to solve some very simple cases. It might be insuficient for your needs, as it requires planning in advance all of the possible parameters.

Suppose I have a macro `ChangeAllFont(newfont as String)` that takes one String parameter.

I declare several utility macros that invoke the macro with some of the desired parameters. For example,

```
Sub ChangeAllFontArial()
 Call ChangeAllFont("Arial")
End Sub
```

and,

```
Sub ChangeAllFontTimes()
 Call ChangeAllFont("Times New Roman")
End Sub
```

And then I might later on invoke the powerpoint either as

```
POWERPNT /M template.ppt ChangeAllFontArial
```

or

```
POWERPNT /M template.ppt ChangeAllFontTimes
```